# Api -> JSON -> MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

First off, the info I have gathered so far, and the self teaching of the ways of JSON has purely been from information from the guys on this site! So a big thanks to everyone..

Ok. I have a platform where I can access their API. This platform issues alerts that I have to act upon..
This is an example of the JSON that is pumped out.

```
[id] => 11573 
[type] => CONDITION 
[status] => TRIGGERED 
[message] => ERROR MESSAGE: It's all gone wrong.. 
[data] => The thingie has popped
[severity] => MAJOR
[result] => 
[source] => ITEM1
[os_user_name] => 
[timestamp] => Tue, 23 Jan 2018 22:28:46 GMT 
[can_reset] => 1 

[device] => Array ( 
[id] => 3 
 )
```

Using PHP, Getting the data from [ID] to [can_reset] into MySQL DB/Table; I've sorted that.
But I just can't get the syntax correct to get the DEVICE->ID into the table..
This is as far as I have got so far, and can't get past it. (Lots of searching online.

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database'); 
if ($conn->errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->error);
    exit();
}



// Create a datetime in RFC1123 format
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$requestDateTime = $dateTime->format(DATE_RFC1123);

// Create signature for request
$stringToSign = getStringToSign('GET', null, null, $requestDateTime, $ALERTS_URL);
$signature = getSignature($SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, $stringToSign);

// Add request headers
$curl->addHeader('Authorization', 'NJ ' . $ACCESS_KEY_ID . ':' . $signature);
$curl->addHeader('Date', $requestDateTime);

// make the request, parse the JSON response and display it 
$response = $curl->get($API_HOST . $ALERTS_URL);

$data = json_decode($response);
foreach ( $data as $inv ) {
    $list_id = $inv->id;
    $list_type = $inv->type;
    $list_status = $inv->status;
    $list_message = $inv->message;
    $list_data = $inv->data;
    $list_severity = $inv->severity;
    $list_result = $inv->result;
    $list_source = $inv->source;
    $list_os_user_name = $inv->os_user_name;
    $list_timestamp = $inv->timestamp;
    $list_device_id = $inv->device->id; <---THIS IS WHAT I CANT GET RIGHT!

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT ignore INTO alerts
             (list_id, list_type, list_status, list_message, list_data, list_severity, list_result, list_source, list_os_user_name, list_timestamp, list_device_id,) 
            VALUES
             ('".$list_id."', '".$list_type."', '".$list_status."', '".$list_message."', '".$list_data."', '".$list_severity."', '".$list_result."', '".$list_source."', '".$list_os_user_name."', '".$list_timestamp."', '".$list_device_id."')");
    if ($result = $sql->execute())
{
  echo "success";
  $sql->free_result();
}
else {
  echo "error";
}
}


$conn->close();
```

Thanks in advance for your assisting this noob at JSON/PHP/MySQL

Comment: Just to add, this is the error in the web logs.
 stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in

Comment: `$inv->device['id']`? Or decode the json with `assoc==true` and access the whole shebang as an array (`$inv['result']` and `$inv['device']['id']`) for consistency.

Comment: ^ Device is an array, not an object. So to access an arrays keys, you should use `['key']`

Comment: How does the json output looks like?

Comment: **pokes** @DougHall include the raw json in your question, to solve what exactly your object looks like. That paste you did above, is partial, hacked, and incomplete.

Comment: **pokes** @DougHall again ... I guess he abandoned his question. I will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the SQL Query you've done.
It was full of errors

Update Full Code

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database'); 
if ($conn->errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->error);
    exit();
}



// Create a datetime in RFC1123 format
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$requestDateTime = $dateTime->format(DATE_RFC1123);

// Create signature for request
$stringToSign = getStringToSign('GET', null, null, $requestDateTime, $ALERTS_URL);
$signature = getSignature($SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, $stringToSign);

// Add request headers
$curl->addHeader('Authorization', 'NJ ' . $ACCESS_KEY_ID . ':' . $signature);
$curl->addHeader('Date', $requestDateTime);

// make the request, parse the JSON response and display it 
$response = $curl->get($API_HOST . $ALERTS_URL);

$data = json_decode($response);
foreach ( $data as $inv ) {
    $list_id = (int)$inv->id;
    $list_type = $conn->real_escape_string($inv->type);
    $list_status = $conn->real_escape_string($inv->status);
    $list_message = $conn->real_escape_string($inv->message);
    $list_data = $conn->real_escape_string($inv->data);
    $list_severity = $conn->real_escape_string($inv->severity);
    $list_result = $conn->real_escape_string($inv->result);
    $list_source = $conn->real_escape_string($inv->source);
    $list_os_user_name = $conn->real_escape_string($inv->os_user_name);
    $list_timestamp = (int)$inv->timestamp;
    $list_device_id = (int)$inv->device['id'];

    $sql = $conn->prepare("
        INSERT ignore INTO alerts
        (list_id, list_type, list_status, list_message, list_data, list_severity, list_result, list_source, list_os_user_name, list_timestamp, list_device_id) 
        VALUES
        ('$list_id', '$list_type', '$list_status', '$list_message', '$list_data', '$list_severity', '$list_result', '$list_source', '$list_os_user_name', '$list_timestamp', '$list_device_id');
    ");

    if($sql->execute()){
      echo "success";
      $sql->free_result();
    } else {
      echo'Error: '.$sql->error;
    }
}


$conn->close();
```

Comment: I now get "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in alerts.php:50" Line 50 is "$list_device_id = $inv->device['id'];"

Comment: @DougHall glad to hear that :)

Comment: @IncredibleHat ok you got your point and i respect that. Check out my edit again for errors!